# How to check if a variable is even in C

Tags: c

How can I check if a variable (an int) is even (that is, not odd) in C without using "%" operator?
I am running on linux platform.

Thank you.

Comment: @abelenky: He wants modular division. It's pretty clear

Comment: I don't think the platform has anything to do with the question. @abelenky The question makes total sense for me.

Comment: @abelenky How to check if a number is even without using modulus? I don't see where's the problem

Comment: @abelenky: Instead of doing number % 2, he wants another way.

Comment: I was confused by the usage of "even".  eg: ***"Is that even a defined variable?"***, vs. ***"Is that numeric value divisible by 2?"***

Comment: @abelenky: that's quite *odd*.

Comment: @abelenky: Had your coffee yet? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (!(v & 1))
```

should be true for even numbers

Comment: I google it and see people using 'return (((a>>1)<<1) == a)'. Why this solution is suggested, what case does it cover that (V&1) does not?

Comment: might be different for negative numbers on systems with certain representations of negative integers?

Answer (score 3):

Try bitwise `AND` with `0x01` to check if last binary digit is 0 or 1.

In case of 0 it's even, whereas in case of 1 it's odd.

Comment: *"0x01"* Why not 0x0001? 1 is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for providing an alternative answer, not that this is any better... You could use the following comparison to check whether an `int` is even *(divisible by 2)*, where `asd` shall be an `int`:

```
asd == asd / 2 * 2;     //returns 1 (true) if asd is even
```